# Pass data between 2 child fragments nested in 1 fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, nested

I've been working on nested fragments in android. I have an activity that contains Fragment A and Fragment A contains Fragment A1 and Fragment A2. and so far, I can successfully pass data from Fragment A1 to its parent fragment(Fragment A) using getParentFragment() (also with Fragment A2). But how can I pass data from Fragment A1 to Fragment A2? What approach must be used and how?

Approach 1:
data from Fragment A1 --> pass data to parent fragment (Fragment A) --> pass data to Fragment A2  (Usual approach in passing data between fragments)

or

Approach 2:
Fragment A1 --> pass data directly to Fragment A2 via setTargetFragment()/getTargetFragment()

I've been experimenting with the set/getTargetFragment() for quite some time now but still can't make it work. Need help guys. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Approach1 is good.. Any communication between two fragments should occur via parentFragment (or parentActivity), so that the "sync" and "single point o access" sustain.

Comment: true but how? Nested fragments don't have id so I can't use the 1st approach.

Comment: They do have ids, for nested fragments, instead of using getSupportFragmentManager();, use getChildSupportFragmentManager()